# How to combine a continuous effect into a function that is for discrete outcome

Tags: logistic, logit, continuous-data, discrete-data

I have a function like this:

log (P(1)/P(0))= a+ sum(h(x))+ g(x),

where a is the intercept, h(x) is a binary outcome: 1, or 0.

g(x) is a continuous variable that contribute to the log of a correct response over an incorrect one. 
However, the sum(h(x)) is discrete, while the g(x) is continuous.

How can I change this function to incorporate both.

Should I change it to log (P(1)/P(0))= a+ sum(h(x))+ log(g(x))?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to change anything. What you described is logistic regression, which is for binary outcome variables. However, g(x) is not an outcome variable so it does not matter whether it is binary, discrete, or continuous.